# Is the existence of elements (sets) postulated in MK?

Tags: set-theory

#### The Background of My Question

I am learning MK (Morse-Kelley set theory). In MK, the primitive notions are: **class** and $\in$.

No doubt, the existence of classes is implicitly postulated in MK as class is a primitive notion; namely, it is postulated to be true that
$$
\exists x\; (x =x).
$$

The term **set** is not a primitive notion, instead, we define the monadic predicate $M(x)$ as "$x$ is a set" or "$x$ is an element"; i.e., the predicate $M(\bullet)$ is defined as
$$
\forall x\; [M(x) \iff\exists y\; (x \in y)]
$$
In this case, if the existence of sets is guaranteed in the system, i.e.,
$$
\exists x\; M(x)
$$
is true, then the term set can be formally defined.

No doubt, the axiom of infinity guaranteed the existence of sets, as it states that there is an inductive class $I$ satisfies $M(I)$, and $\emptyset \in I$ is a necessary condition of the axiom.

#### Why I Ask For Help

When I am writing my notes for MK (I intend to arrange them in to a book so that I can better see the landscape of the theory), I have to introduce axioms one by one. It is easy to find that the MK-axioms are irrelevant to the existence of sets. But, I don't know if the definitions such as "power sets" can be valid or not before the axiom of infinity is introduced, since they define specific types of sets and hence require the existence of sets.

#### The Question

My question is: **is the existence of sets postulated since $\in$ is a primitive notion?**

I suspect it is not, since, even if $V = \emptyset$, it is vacuously true that
$$
\forall x\; \forall y\; (x \in y).
$$
Besides, in set theory, a relation $R$ can be define on $\emptyset = \emptyset \times \emptyset$.

But, on the other hand, if $V = \emptyset$, then every relation $*$ between classes satisfies the same pattern; I mean, it is also vacuously true that
$$
\forall x\; \forall y\; (x * y).
$$

In this case, does $\in$ remain any specific meaning in the system?

Comment: In my view, the one-sorted approach to Kelley-Morse is misguided and I never use it myself. Sure, it is equivalent to the two-sorted presentation, in the sense of bi-interpretation, but because the nature of sets and proper classes is so different, very little of the motivation for the axioms is naturally expressible in the one-sorted theory. If you separate the domain into two sorts, the sets and the classes, then everything becomes much more clear.

Comment: But also, why not simply adopt a nontriviality axiom $\exists x\ x=x$? This is a consequence of infinity, yes, but one wants this axiom when considering versions of KM for finite set theory, where infinity is denied, but the rest of the theory works as expected for finite sets.

Comment: "If you separate the domain into two sorts, the sets and the classes, then everything becomes much more clear." Do you mean that I should take **set** as a primitive notion also?

Comment: There are standard axiomatizations of Kelley-Morse set theory (and also Gödel-Bernays set theory) that have two sorts, the sets and the classes. For example, see https://jdh.hamkins.org/km-implies-conzfc/. This is a standard Henkin approach to second-order logic, where one equips a first-order model with a collection of classes fulfilling a natural class comprehension axiom.

Comment: Ah I remember now, in [this Gödel's paper](https://archive.org/details/dli.ernet.469796/page/4/mode/2up), both set and class are primitive notions, and rather than consider "sets are elements and vise versa", he only give the axiom in Group A that: **elements are sets** – the converse is not given.

Comment: Thank you again Joel for my second question. I will carefully read the article in the link. Now I have another question: Is the listed axioms on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse–Kelley_set_theory) standard? Because I need the full list of the axioms. And according to the definition of the monadic predicate $M(x)$ in this article, set is redundant among the primitive notions.

Comment: The Wikipedia article is using the one-sorted axiomatization, which is not the version often used in the literature. Also, they use the so-called "Limitation of Size" axiom, which in my view is also misguided, since this axiom is simply a unnecessary trick for combining replacement and global choice into one statement. I know of no philosophical motivation for this axiom that is separate from the motivations for replacement and global choice separately. So I prefer to state the axioms that are the focus of our philosophical discussions about them.

Comment: I see. So, are you suggesting that I should choose a different theory? Do you have any suggestion for learning the philosophy? (I started learning math a few years ago because I have some philosophical questions in mind, so I really want to know about them.)

Comment: No, it is the same theory, just a different equivalent way of presenting it, which accords more closely with how the theory is used by researchers. It is not a different theory, but it avoids the silly issues about extracting the notion of set from the notion of class and the questions about whether the concept of set is "primitive", whatever that means. It also makes more clear that KM is a restriction of second-order ZFC, studied by Zermelo, and it makes the relationship with GBC (also known as NGB) more transparent.

Comment: Can you send me a pdf link for the two-sort version of KM without the limitation of size please? I find nothing on Google... :(

Comment: See https://victoriagitman.github.io/talks/2018/01/03/the-emerging-zoo-of-second-order-set-theories.html. The axiomatization is easy, and you can work it out yourself and prove that it is equivalent to the one-sorted theory. Limitation of size = global choice + replacement over the other axioms, and this is also easy to prove.

Comment: Thank you very much Joel! Please wait for my last question: how do you think the set theory in Gödel's book *The Consistency Of The Axiom Of Choice and Of The Generalized Continuum Hypothesis With The Axioms Of Set Theory*? I found his set theory is very much similar to MK but much more conservative. Only in his theory the union of arbitrary classes is invalid in his theory that makes me unhappy :((( – still I appreciate the conservation of the theory.

Comment: Yes, Gödel-Bernays set theory GBC (also called NGB) is strictly weaker than KM, since it has only the first-order class comprehension axiom, and so it doesn't allow the second-order quantifier $\exists C$ in comprehension (and $\exists C$ is what you call union of arbitrary classes, based on your other question). In particular, GBC is conservative over ZFC for assertions about sets, whereas KM is not  because it implies Con(ZFC).

Comment: Thanks a lot Joel! I see you soon!

Comment: @WenchuanZhao, No the existence of a set is not postulated at the background logic of the mono-sorted version of MK . The existence of a class is! So, you need to add existence axioms for sets, usually infinity would work. But if you are considering finite fragments of MK, then you need to add the axiom of set existence which is: $\exists x \exists y: y \in x$. If you are working with the mono-sorted version of MK presented in the wikipedia, then the empty class is a model of MK-Infinity.

Comment: Thank you! I realized that no axioms but infinity's truth value is relevant to the postulation, since then can be vacuously true if the universal class $\mathscr U = \{x: M(x)\}$ is empty. So, maybe in the finite fragments the existence of sets can be postulated and then prove it after the axiom of infinity is introduced?

Comment: @WenchuanZhao, all the axioms in the Wikipedia version except Infinity begins with universal quantification, that's why the empty set would be a model of it, since all of them would be vacuously true, however since most of the time a first order logic theory is supposed to have a nonempty domain, then we can have just a single empty class. Now the finite fragments of MK can have one or more sets by stipulating the relevant axioms, the finite fragments of MK doesn't have an axiom of infinity, they may have set pairing, union, power, size limitation etc..

Comment: @Zuhair Al-Johar Yes, so I suspect I can explain to my friends about the system with an additional postulation: $\exists x: \exists: y: x \in y$, since it doesn't break the system and all axioms are independent. (You know, I am a self-teaching, so story-telling might be the best practice.)

Comment: @WenchuanZhao, Yes of course You can add a set existence axiom. No problem. Actually that was already there. Also you can see the [talk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Morse%E2%80%93Kelley_set_theory#Axiom_of_Infinity_can_assert_setness_instead_of_existence) page on the Wikipedia article itself.

Comment: @Zuhair Al-Johar Thank you! this page helps a lot (I also notice they are talking about the quantifier of the axiom of power set is $\forall$ but not $\exists$ as it is in ZFC; for the sake of independency of the axioms, I do like the $\forall$-version better.)

Comment: @WenchuanZhao, I see what you mean. I also like the $\forall$-version better. For any set A the power class of it is a set, is better than saying for any set A there exists a power class of it that is a set. Because existence is already taken care for by class comprehension, so we don't need to repeat matters. I agree!

Comment: Ah sorry, I mean the version [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse–Kelley_set_theory#mw-content-text): $\forall a \forall p[(Ma \land \forall x[x \in p \leftrightarrow \forall y (y \in x \rightarrow y \in a)])\rightarrow Mp]$.

Comment: If this version is assumed, then it is independent from the replacement and the specification (no matter they are theorems or axioms)

Comment: @Zuhair Al-Johar yes indeed!